# Passing sequential list to for loop

Tags: bash, seq

I have a list of files to put through a for loop. They are named

```
FA2_00032.png, FA2_00033.png, etc
```

I have variables `$imID` which contains FA2 string, `$startFrame` which contains the start frame (e.g. 00034) and `$endFrame` which contains to end frame (e.g. 00894).

I have managed to get the list of relevant files using:

```
eval echo ${imageID}_{${startFrame}..${endFrame}}.png;
```

This outputs

> FA2_00034 FA2_00035 FA2_00036 etc

But now I need to pass this to the for loop. That is,

```
for file in *the above list*
```

where *the above list* is the block quoted list above. `$file` should contain `FA2_00034`, `FA2_00035`, etc for use in the for loop.

Comment: BTW, this is [BashPitfalls #33](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D)

Comment: Beware, there are some bad answers in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, @chepner: what do you think of using `xargs` for this? (eg. `seq ${startFrame} ${endFrame} | xargs -I {} printf "%s_%05d.png\\n" ${imageID} {}`). Seems like a nice way without using a loop.

Comment: @l'L'l, `seq` is neither part of bash nor part of the POSIX spec. It's not guaranteed to be available, nor to have any particular behavior when it *is* present. And `xargs printf`, using `/usr/bin/printf`, is much more expensive than using the `printf` shell builtin.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Interesting, I didn't realize the `xargs` was actually using it's own `printf` — thank you for the reply/advice/tips as always!

Comment: It's more that the shell provides a builtin printf, but as an external executable xargs can't directly call shell builtins, so unless you do something that starts a shell, like `xargs sh -c 'printf "$0" "$@"' 'FA2_%05d.png\n'`, it has to use the external implementation from the PATH -- so less xargs doing something special, and more the shell doing something special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a C-style for loop, not `eval`+`{...}`, for tasks like this. `printf` can be used to assemble the file name from the current integer. The syntax `10#$foo` ensures that the value of `$foo` is treated as a decimal (not an octal) number if it includes leading 0s.

```
imageID=FA2
startFrame=00034
endFrame=00894

for ((i=10#startFrame; i<=10#$endFrame; i++)); do
    printf -v file '%s_%05d.png' "$imageID" "$i"
    echo "Operating on $file" >&2
done
```

Comment: Worked great - thanks